# Where to add exception handling for "Error: socket hang up"

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm using node.js to post JSON records to an API that stores the records in a database.

There can be lots of records (lets say 100.000), and to avoid too big requests (to long response times), I send 2500 records per request to the API.

Despite of this, I randomly can receive the following error:

```
events.js:167
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: socket hang up
    at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:322:15)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:23)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1092:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1092:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

My API works very hard when this import takes place. I'm not only inserting the records. I'm also doing some verification checks before insert. I guess the reason is because the request gets timeout.

My first thought was to add handling of this exception, and doing retry of the request if it fails.

I've tried to add handling of the exception by adding a try/catch clause around the request code. This does not catch the exception.

Normally an unhandled exception shows reference to were in my code the exception I triggered from. In this case, based on the error message, its only reference to language classes/modules.

The question is: Where should I add handling of this exception?

Comment: where are you doing the requests? can you share some code?

Comment: We need to see the code the leads to this error.  The best solution is to change that code to avoid the error in the first place.

Comment: Here is the code: https://pastebin.com/qJxLUQsv

Comment: You guys might already pushed me in the right direction. :) Reviewing my code. I was doing the sub function and amount of connections check, recalling the sub function. But body is not a parameter of the sub function. This might not be relevant in this scenario, because I'm using await when calling Post, but I've simplified the code a bit now and looks better so far (https://pastebin.com/F8C5U3JN). The connections thing was originally for limiting GET requests when working async.

Comment: To fast there.. Ok! Something apparently happens to Docker (were api are running).

Comment: Probably: Container exited because of an Out Of Memory issue.. Not relevant here then. Thanks anyway..

Comment: Relevant code here needs to be IN the actual question (for a variety of reasons), not only in an external link.